# One question from ISTQB security exam, how to test SQL injection efficiently?

Tags: security-testing, istqb

If we are to use equivalent partitioning technique, which one of the following answers is the most efficient to test against SQL injection?

1. bbbbb,12345,'
2. %, ', @, abn123
3. ', ab123
4. '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***The answer is 3.***

> bbbbb,12345,'

This answer is correct, but from equivalent partitioning point of view, it offers two valid inputs, bbbbb and 12345, from valid input partitioning.

> %, ', @, abn123

This answer has three valid inputs from valid input partitioning.

> ', 123

This answer has one valid input and one escape character.

> '

This answer has only got one escape character, no valid input at all.

Please bear in mind, ISTQB exam does not cover everything, letting alone SQL injection techniques. I suggest you spend some time studying SQL injection, there is a good link here. [SQL Injection OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)